# BroadCast Admin message to Each Session User

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to inform every user to save their work and logout so that admin can reset iis or do some changes in the asp.net MVC application server.

looping through session object collection is not thread safe that is what i have learned.

any other ideas?

and even if i can get hold of active sessions how do i send a message to those clients ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Save the message in a database and query the database for every request to see if a message exist.

Comment: i am already doing that on each request. But i am hoping to initiate this response from the server itself, not after any user request.

Comment: Then you need to push the message to the client, which is a new requirement. You can do that using AJAX polling to some action on the server. The server action can then query the database.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a poorly-defined requirement.

Serious maintenance should be done at a specific time, and users should be alerted to that time window well in advance.

Simply restarting IIS is a pretty quick procedure... is there any reason users would lose their work when simply restarting IIS?  While I've been filling out this StackOverflow answer, for instance, they could have restarted the server a dozen times.  Once I hit Post, if the server is down, it'll either timeout and leave my work in the textarea, or else it will connect successfully if the server is back in time.

If I'm not submitting data, but just clicking a link, the same applies:  either the browser times out, in which case a simple refresh is enough once the server is back up, or it eventually takes the user where they want to go.

If you're doing pure AJAX requests you will need to handle a missing server yourself, rather than relying on the browser to do it, but you'd need to work that out anyway because of the Eight Fallacies of Distributed Computing #1: "The network is reliable."  (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing)

So, I'd actually push back on that requirement.  They're asking you to do something that won't really meet the need (users don't lose data, have a reasonably good experience), that will become complicated, and that will be a brittle solution in the end.

Comment: It is because the session gets lost and all the users in the middle of their entry start fuming at once on the poor admin. In the 1st few months of the deployment builds are frequently updated which requires iisreset and hence the need of a user warning.

Comment: That sounds frustrating!  Perhaps the requirement should be "session data survives server restarts"?  That's usually a lot easier to implement than the fancy stuff... just store your session data in the StateServer or in SQL Server.  It's only if you use the default "in-process" session storage that all user sessions are wiped when restarting.

Comment: that is just one of the requirement. The manager wants to assign some work or schedule a meeting ... etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case for SignalR!

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR